# Property [participants_count] does not exist but exists and can be dumped

Tags: laravel-8

I have 2 tables, evenements and participants, represented by 2 models Evenement and Participant.
Those entities are belongsToMany related, so I have a third table evenement_participant following Laravel's naming conventions, and inside are foreign evenement_id and participant_id columns.

I'm able to retrieve the relationship and I can

```
dd($evenement->participants)
```

which gives me a collection of participants.
In my controller, I have this db call:

```
$evenements = Evenement::withCount(['participants' => function($query) {
  $query->where('is_active', 1);
}])
```

This withCount generates a participants_count attribute for each evenement.
In my blade view, there is a for-each loop on the evenements collection, and somewhere I do this:

```
$evenement->participants_count
```

and I face this error:

> Property [participants_count] does not exist on this collection
> instance.

However, if instead I do the following in the same blade view

```
@dd($evenement->participants_count)
```

it dumps me the count.

I dropped all the evenements to keep just one for testing, and I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, made a typo in a condition inside my blade loop